# In Firefox, if the webpage is scrolled down, the dropdown doesnot open/work

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

In Firefox, if the webpage is scrolled down, the dropdown doesnot open/work. Hence for all my selenium tests fail. How to address this issue? The webpage is designed as per Kendo grid UI. It's a common problem identified by Kendo guys.

If the page is scrolled up, this issue is not there, but the execution starts, suddenly the page will scroll down by itself and any dropdown items which are there in that page, wont work.

Comment: I think we're seeing the same thing.  If you scroll to the bottom of the page to where it hard stops at the bottom, then try to click a kendo dropdown, it opens and closes real quick.  If you scroll up as little as 1 px they'll work again.  Is this the same you're seeing?

Comment: Yes it is the same thing Mike

Answer (score 0):

You can try scrolling to element:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("id_of_element"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

Or altervatively you can also try using a bigger window (like fullscreen):

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```